# Generating new column value based on correlating 2 or more rows

Tags: pyspark

I have a usecase where I want to generate new column value, consider a pyspark data frame like this:

```
User   |  Product  |   Event       | ...
----------------------------------------
ram       apple         viewed
ram       apple         carted
bill      samsung       viewed
bill      samsung       carted
bill      samsung       bought
```

I want to process the above dataframe using PySpark and generate additional column in this dataframe as follow:

```
User   |  Product  |   Event       | isBought
----------------------------------------
ram       apple         carted         0
bill      samsung       carted         1
```

So, I need to add a column isBought whose value is 0 if carted but not bought but 1 if carted and bought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `collect_list()` to get the list of 'Events' for each User-Product combo, and then use `array_contains` to execute your logic.

If 'carted' and 'bought' -> `1`. If 'carted' but not 'bought' -> `0`
For any other case, I'm filling `null`.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.groupBy("User", "Product").agg(collect_list(col("Event")).alias("isBought"))\
    .withColumn("isBought", when((array_contains("isBought", "carted")\
     & array_contains("isBought", "bought")), 1).when((array_contains("isBought",\
      "carted") & ~array_contains("isBought", "bought")), 0)\
      .otherwise(None)).show()

+----+-------+--------+
|User|Product|isBought|
+----+-------+--------+
| ram|  apple|       0|
|bill|samsung|       1|
+----+-------+--------+
```